# What are some good books to learn more about Neem Karoli Baba?

Tags: book-recommendation

I am really interested to know more about saint Neem Karoli Baba - the great Hanuman Bhakta. I am looking for a book to understand more about His teachings.

Personally I am looking for a book which gives daily life and teachings of Him. Sort of like **I AM THAT**(Nisargadatta Maharaja) or **Talks With Ramana Maharshi**(Ramana Maharshi) or **Gospel of Ramakrishna**(Ramakrishna Paramhansa) . That is in the same format if possible.

Comment: There was a Western devotee of his named Ram Dass (who has given up the body already). He published several books on Neem Karoli Babaji. You might like to google his name.